# How much should be our expense and savings ratio?

Tags: india, savings, salary, expenses

What is the right ratio of expense to savings ?

is 80-20 alright ?

Although we follow high standard living, here in Bharat(India) we can save upto 50%.

Comment: There isn't an exact number for that. It depends on your circumstances and your future plans.

Comment: The typical metric is savings as a percent of gross income, and for that, 10% is a common goal. To DC's point - the rest of your circumstances may suggest this is far too much or not nearly enough. The question is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what country you're in, but you might [find this graph](https://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/series/PSAVERT) interesting because most don't even have 20% of their income saved in the United States.  I've read stories that state that the Chinese have a 30+% savings rate, though a lot of their savings is due to the fact that they are directly responsible for their retirement, so that's taken into consideration.

As for rules, [this link](http://www.getrichslowly.org/blog/2009/03/09/25-favorite-financial-rules-of-thumb/) covers some of the problems with hard rules on savings:

> The standard rule of thumb is to save at least 10% of your income. I
>   think a better goal is to aim for 20%. At MSN Money, Liz Weston writes
>   that if you’re young, you can follow this rule of thumb: “Save 10% for
>   basics, 15% for comfort, 20% to escape.”

You won't find an official rule on savings.  I'd advise to save as much as you can **until** you have an emergency fund that can sustain you for [x] number of months (years) that is satisfactory to you.  For instance, if the longest you've ever been umemployed is 4 months, and you would feel confident with 6 months in emergency savings, get to that point by saving as much as you can, but once you get there, how much you save after that is up to you; generally 10-20% is the *minimum* I've seen advised by most financial professionals.